# PHP regular expression to extract date from string

Tags: php, regex

It's nothing that I am with this **regular expressions** stuff. I don't get the regular expression for my requirement. Here is the string format that I have to split with a regular expression in PHP.

```
ABCxxxx_ABCDEfghi_YYYYmmddhhmmss.mp4
```

In this string,

```
ABC -word(case sensitive)
x -any digit
ABCDEfghi -word(case sensitive)
YYYYmmddhhmmss -timestamp value
.mp4 -word preceded with a dot(.)
```

All I need is to extract the date from this string.

ie, take `YYYYmmdd` to a variable.

I know that this is not the way of writing it, but I tried. Here is the attempt:

```
$s = "ABC0000_ABCDEfghi_20000101223344.mp4";
$regex = "/\ABC[0-9]{4}_ABCDEfghi_&var=[0-9]{8}[0-9]{6}+\.mp4/";
$matches = array();
$s = preg_match($regex, $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

THE ERROR:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\wamp\www\Test\regex.php on
>   line 6 Call Stack Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0000 241296
>   {main}( ) ..\regex.php:0

I am stuck. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the `\` before `A`
2. Don't use `&var`, instead you need to use capturing groups.

   ```
   $regex = '~ABC[0-9]{4}_ABCDEfghi_([0-9]{8})[0-9]{6}\.mp4~';
   ```
3. Add start `^` and end `$` anchors if necessary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uV8qU5/1)

```
$s = "ABC0000_ABCDEfghi_20000101223344.mp4";
$regex = '~^ABC[0-9]{4}_ABCDEfghi_([0-9]{8})[0-9]{6}\.mp4$~';
preg_match($regex, $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
20000101
```

Comment: Is it possible to split the same date as `YYYY`, `mm` and `dd` into $matches[] in the same regular expression?

Comment: Yes, that was all what I needed for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=_)\d+(?=\.mp4)
```

Simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/4

```
$re = "/(?<=_)\\d+(?=\\.mp4)/";
$str = "ABC0000_ABCDEfghi_20000101223344.mp4";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```